# Identifying the Car

Tags: vehicle-identification

Can anyone help me identify the year, make and model of this car?

I would greatly appreciate anyone that can help me. Please!

Thank you so much for anyone that is looking.

[image]

Comment: Which country was the photo taken?

Comment: BMW X3 or X1?  Hard to say from the pic tbh

Comment: The image is quite poor in quality but to my eye, it looks like one of the BMX X-series cars.  Possibly an early X5, Perhaps an X1 or X3?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it's a first-generation BMW X3 (E83) - the ridge along the top of the doors is different to the Volvos, and you can see the distinctive upsweep to the bottom of the rearmost window.

Answer (score 2):

I also say BMW.  Although similar to the Volvo XC60, where the side windows meet the body is different. Also, the front end is square where the XC60 looks more raked.

Here is a pic of the first generation BMW X3:
[image: First Gen BMW X3]

Answer (score 1):

Without a much clearer and larger picture I have to take an educated guess. It looks like a Volvo SUV XC model. As for the year hard to say.

Comment: My first thought was the first generation XC90 as well (first gen because there's no stripe across the headlight), but there are several discrepancies. The angle of the rear glass at the back bottom side is completely wrong. The body line on the side of the car which extends from mid front fender to mid rear fender doesn't exist on an XC90. The side view mirror is also wrong. While the wheels can be changed, they don't match up to stock ones.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I did say It was a guess. All these SUV look alike. It could also be something from Acura as well. I tried zooming the image 300% ....no joy.

Comment: Wasn't dogging you out ... just pointing out what I was seeing. Yah, zooming in didn't work too well for me, either. A google image drop gave me *Sport Utility Vehicle*, so no joy there, either.

Comment: Hey, I'll +1 you, because now I believe you were right (as you can tell from my entry). I forgot all about the XC60 until I saw one on the street earlier today.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Are we good or what.? ....LOL

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it is a Volvo XC60. Here's a clear picture of one:

[image]

In the picture you can see the side panel body line and the lower sweep of the window. This is a first generation XC60, so model years are between 2008-2017.